# SignalR WebSocket "Connecting" state takes too long after try to reconnect

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-core, websocket, signalr

I have a really simple .Net Core 3.1 application for testing that starts a connection on signalR. Here's the function I have in the front end that starts the connection.

```
const App: React.FC = () => {

  const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl("/hub")
    .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Trace)
    .build();

  connection.start().catch(err => document.write(err));

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.tsx</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Also here's my back end code.

```
 public class Startup
    {
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSignalR();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseDefaultFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapHub<ChatHub>("/hub");
            });

            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:3000");                

            });


        }
    }
```

When I first load or when I wait around 2 minutes before refresh the app. It connects immediately. Here's an example of the log I'm getting:

> [2020-01-07T16:53:23.217Z] Debug: Selecting transport 'WebSockets'.
>
> **[2020-01-07T16:53:23.218Z]** Trace: (WebSockets transport) Connecting.
>
> **[2020-01-07T16:53:23.531Z]** Information: WebSocket connected to wss://localhost:44344/hub?id=6pXMScFZez-Vv72C73Etfw.

But when I refresh the browser, it stays in "connecting" state and after around 2 minutes it finally connects. Here's an example of the log in this case:

> [2020-01-07T16:53:49.069Z] Debug: Selecting transport 'WebSockets'.
>
> **[2020-01-07T16:53:49.070Z]** Trace: (WebSockets transport) Connecting.
>
> **[2020-01-07T16:55:25.574Z]** Information: WebSocket connected to wss://localhost:44344/hub?id=BPT4DkdPVgBj-nkOarAyNQ.

Question:
Is there any configuration available on signalR to avoid this wait before reconnect? (This is something that is happening only on .Net Core 3.1, Never had this issue with previous versions)

Thanks.

Comment: You are asking if there is a way to for example, wait only 15 seconds on the connect and when it passes the 15 seconds try to reconnect again?

Comment: Hi @Kiril1512, actually no. I'm asking how I can configure signalrR to avoid the "connecting" time showed on the second log. This time it's always around 2 minutes but never happened on the first connect(the one showed on the first log).

Comment: That is definitely not normal and SignalR shouldn't be doing anything to cause this. I can't reproduce this with a non React app. Would it be possible to grab the server logs and a network trace to see why it's taking 2 minutes to connect?